# Shape and diversity of chemotrophic plants

Tags: biology, evolution, xenobiology

I posted a question similar to this but that was about how these plants would work, this is about how they could look like.
So in a tidally locked planet I'm working on there are plants which inhabit its dark side and caves, and these plants have entered a symbiotic relationship with chemothrophic bacteria which live on their cells. These bacteria use the hydrogen sulfide, methane and oxygen in the air to make food for themselves and the plant, and get safety in return. (H2S + 6CH4 + 3o2 -> C6H12o6 + 7H2S)
My question is: with such chemotrophic properties, what kind of structure could these plants use to maximize their food production? I'm thinking maybe they could use the wind?

Comment: Given the diversity of plants on earth, how do you expect this question to not be too broad under our prohibition of questions with many valid answers? As a general rule we prohibit questions where the intent is to brainstorm or generate ideas.

Comment: Safety from what?

Comment: If they are chemotrophic, can you really call them plants? Also, with "maybe they can use the wind." If they use wind, they aren't chemotrophic, they are kinetotrophic(or some other name like that).

Answer (score 2):

**Tree with roots.**

[image]

[source](https://odonovanlandscaping.com/take-care-when-planting-a-new-tree-over-old-roots/)

Your organism contains bacteria that want to oxidize methane and H2S with oxygen.  They will not find the oxygen in the same place as the methane and H2S because if these gases coexisted the oxygen would abiogenically oxidize them.

Your organism fetches the H2S and methane from below the surface, where it is in a deep anaerobic environment.  To get down to where this stuff is it needs roots.

It then brings these molecules up and oxidizes them in the air.  To do this it needs to maximize surface area, like a lung or a gill.  Plants maximize surface area for a different reason - to capture more light energy.  The crown of a tree is not so different from a lung.  More surface area means more access to oxygen which might be in short supply in darkside caves full of creatures consuming it.

Maybe the tree can move.  I could imagine a colony of these might move in sync, to generate a breeze and air exchange, carrying out the CO2 and SO2 wastes and bringing in more O2.

I might imagine that the H2O waste is not released with the SO2 to avoid acidifying the local area.  H2O is pumped back out through the roots, to keep the ground wet and facilitate movement of H2S and methane through the substrate.